# How to update dynamic param in NextJS 13 app router?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

I have a route `user/[userId]/forms` in which I have a `layout.tsx` that contains a Select/Dropdown menu.

This dropdown contains options where the values are id's of different forms. When the user selects an item from the dropdown I want to navigate to `user/[userId]/forms/[formId]`. The way I'm trying to do this now is like this:

```
import { useRouter, usePathName, useParams } from "next/navigation";

const router = useRouter();
const pathName = usePathName();
const params = useParams();

const handleOnChange = (formId: string) => {
  if(params.formId) {
    router.push(pathName.replace(params.formId, formId)); //If a form is already selected, change it.
  } else {
    router.push(`${pathName}/${formId}`); //If no form is selected, open that.
  }
}
```

This works but it feels so manual and potentially flaky. Like if the url ever were to contain a string matching the formId, that would be replaced instead.

Is there a better way to set the value of a dynamic route segment?

Comment: a cleaner way can be `router.push(\`user/${userId}/forms/${formId}\`)`